# Images dont apear on a local host

Tags: html, image

I am trying to display a couple images on a local host but it always apears as a little photo icon.
Everything works except the images.

```
<script>
        function light(sw) {
            var pic;
            if(sw == 0) {
                pic = "pic_bulboff.gif";
            } else {
                pic = "pic_bulbon.gif";
            }
            document.getElementById("Blub").src = pic;
        }


    </script>
    <img id="Bulb" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="100">

    <p>
        <button type="button" onclick="light(0)">Turn bulb off</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="light(1)">Turn bulb on</button>
    </p>
```

The image files are in the same folder as my .html so it shouldnt have issues with diretion. And all the pictures are named correctly. I have searched for a solution and found many people with similar problems but not a solution. Any ideas on why this is happening?

[Here is my files folder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpFtc.png)

Comment: Can you add a picture of all of the files within the folder containing your .html files and pictures?

Comment: @SidarthNuthi I attached a picture of my files workspace.

Comment: There is a typo in your code. `id="Bulb"`, and `getElementById("Blub")`

Answer (score 0):

This could be a rendering problem as you are calling the image in js before it is rendered. Put the image tag before the script tag.